# How can I do the sum of two hh:mm fields in SQL Server?

Tags: database, sql-server-2005, aggregate-functions

I have to add minutes of a column then convert them to hours. I found a query to convert minutes to hrs:

```
declare @mins int

set @mins = 750.00

select cast(@mins/60 as varchar(5)) + ':' + RIGHT('0' + cast(@mins%60 as varchar(2)), 2) as [TotalTime]
enter code here
```

But I am not able to add the minutes. I think I need to create stored procedure but, I'm unable to do so. Please help.

I have tried following sp

```
USE [MailEmployeeDb]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
create PROCEDURE [dbo].[AddHrs]
(
@Project nvarchar(50),
@mins int,
@assigned_by nvarchar(50),
@Emolyee_id nvarchar(50),
@Date datetime,
@Status varchar(50),
@Hours varchar(50),
@Name_Emp varchar(50)
)      
AS      
BEGIN 
@mins = select sum(hours) from Task_SheetTbl where Project=@Project,Name_Emp=@Name_Emp,Hours=@Hours,Date=@Date,assigned_by=@assigned_by
select cast(@mins/60 as varchar(5)) + ':' + RIGHT('0' + cast(@mins%60 as varchar(2)), 2)
END
```

But not successfull....Plz hlp if anyone can corect this sp

create table script

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Task_SheetTbl](
    [Emolyee_id] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Project] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Date] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [Assigned_By] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Status] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Comments] [nvarchar](100)  NULL,
    [Task] [nvarchar](100)  NULL,
    [Hours] [varchar](50)  NULL
)
```

This is set of values

```
    monika  erp 01.11.2011 5:31:01 AM   mmm Completed   hhhhhhhhh   mmm 750.00
mona    erp 01.11.2011 12:00:00 AM  me  ccc cccc    cccc    700.0
son ehandel 01.11.2011 12:00:00 AM  mon rrr rrrr    rrr 30.00
monika  erp 02.11.2011 10:56:44 AM  jjjjj   Completed   nop nnnnn   0.50
NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
```

Result ==I need to add all the hours values appearing on respective search like i need to know how many hrs erp project is undertaken by employees.for how many hrs employees worked on particular project..

Comment: Can you be more specific? Show your table definition (CREATE TABLE statement), some data (INSERT statement), desired result.

Comment: This is My create table script

Comment: Where is it? Just add all this in your question.

Comment: CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Task_SheetTbl](
 [Emolyee_id] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
 [Project] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
 [Date] [datetime] NOT NULL,
 [Assigned_By] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
 [Status] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
 [Comments] [nvarchar](100)  NULL,
 [Task] [nvarchar](100)  NULL,
 [Hours] [varchar](50)  NULL
)

Comment: This is MS SQL Server syntax. You asked about MySQL; and tagged mysql.

Comment: sry for tht..If u can hlp me on this...then plz hlp

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you might need to create a SP, but this query should work as per your question title "how do I add"

```
SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(TIME_TO_SEC('22:00:00')+7200) AS totaltime
```

Where 22:00:00 could be your start time column .. and 7200 is the seconds taken to complete something.

Answer (score 0):

It is not very clear what are you intending to do here. The question reads "how can I do the sum of two HH:MM fields" but from your code samples it seems that you do not need to add two HH:MM fields but instead show the total minutes in HH:MM format.

Anyways, assuming the latter, this is what you might do:

```
SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(hours) * 60)
FROM Task_SheetTbl 
WHERE Project = 'abc'
AND Name_Emp = 'def'
AND ...
...
;
```

where, SUM(hours) will give you @mins in your code.

Also, the SP code that you have given does not seem to be a valid syntax in MySQL. Are you sure you are able to create that SP?